# Arrays and Pointers +Errors

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here is the assignment:

> Your goal is to write a program that displays a series of whole numbers from input in reverse order. Your
> program will prompt the user for the number of values in this list, which it will use as the size for a dynamic
> array declared after this prompt.

The array `size` is unknown, the `value` is the pointer, and the `sub` has to be assigned before the loop.

Here are the steps:

1. Declare variables, but don't "allocate the memory the memory for the pointer yet". Do this after prompting the user to enter the values.
2. Prompt user to enter the numbers of values to be listed. (There has to be a message for the user in case they enter a **negative** number). Then use the keyword `new` for the pointer.
3. Prompt the user to enter the values
4. Display the values in reverse.
5. Use the keyword `delete` for the dynamic array.

While I'm trying to run the program, the error was:

> error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
> `for(int sub = 0; sub < size; size--)`
> --------------------------------------^
> error: lvalue required as decrement operand
> `for (int sub = 0; sub > size; size--)`
> ------------------------------------------------------^

Also, I am not sure what the keyword `new` does.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size, array;

    cout << "How many values would you like to enter? ";
    cin >> array;
    
    
    int value;
    int *array = new int[size];
    
    if (size > 0)
    {
        for (int sub = 0; sub < size; size++)
        {
            cout << "Enter value #" << size << ": ";
            cin >> value;
        }
        while (size > 0);
    }
    
    else
    {
        while (size < 0)
        {
            cout << "Size must be positive." << endl;
            cout << "How many values would you like to enter? ";
            cin >> size;
        }
    }
    
    cout << "Here are the values you entered in reverse order: \n";
    
    for (int sub = size - 1; sub >= 0; size--) 
    {
        cout << "Value #" << size << " :" << value << endl;
    }
    
    delete[] array;

    return 0;
}
```

PS: I know `size` is supposed to be unknown, but I've encountered another error saying

> storage size of ‘size’ isn’t known

So, I add numbers to avoid that error. 
**Edit**:So I changed the code thanks to @MikeCAT, but this error said `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length what():  std::bad_array_new_length`. This was because I enter a **negative** number for the `size`, which was supposed to happen for the `if`  statement. Also, I need the `size` to start at **1**  after the user enters how many values they want to enter,  but the `size` always starts at the number that was entered.

Comment: `size[10]` is out-of-range for 9-element `size`. Consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @MikeCAT I don't think that is an option as a dynamically allocated array is required (`size` not strictly fitting that is an other issue, but that is beside the point)

Comment: For `new` you can look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new. It is a bit heavy but it should give a good idea on how dynamically allocated arrays/memory works in `c++`

Comment: `storage size of 'size' is unknown`: You can NOT have variables on the stack (i.e. locally within a function), whose size is not known at compilation. Some compilers allow it but it is not standard `c++`. Again to do that you need `new`. `new int[size]`, does a couple of things. Allocates memory for `size` number of `int`s. Returns the pointer to the start of the allocated memory (makes sure alignment is fine, initialises some time, etc.). This memory is not deallocated. You need `delete` for that

Comment: So change the code thanks to @MikeCAT, but this error said `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length what():  std::bad_array_new_length`.

Answer (score 1):

As the assignment says, you should

1. Read a value
2. Allocate a dynamic array using the value read as its size
3. Read the numbers for the array

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    // read a number (size of a dynamic array)
    int numElements;
    std::cin >> numElements;

    // allocate a dynamic array
    int *array = new int[numElements];

    // read values for the dynamic array
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        std::cin >> array[i];
    }

    // print the values in reversed order
    for (int i = numElements - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << array[i] << '\n';
    }

    // de-allocate the array
    delete[] array;

    // exit normally
    return 0;
}
```

Error handling and non-essensial messages are omitted. Try adding them.

Comment: *Try adding them.* is good advice. If you never check for errors, errors will always come as a surprise. Being surprised all of the time is inefficient as hell.

Comment: _int *array = new int[numElements]_ there was an error in this line saying "conflicting declaration ‘int* array" with `int *array = new int[size]`